# Sliding up and down Expandanable list view content

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing a drag and drop expandable list view. where I can drag any child from one group to 
another group . Problem that I am facing is when expandable list have more then 50 records(rows)  It show
15 records on the screen visible area and other 35 is off the screen (invisible area).Here is the  problem scenario starts
when I want to drag my 1 group child to 35th group i cant scroll down to 35th group because  35th record exist
in invisible area of the screen. I need a solution some thing like when I start drag the child of first group and want to
move it to  group number 35 list automatically scroll towards up and I can see 35th record on to the mobile 
visible area.Keep in mind that I want to drag my child from one group to other gourp . Hope I make my situation some how clear to you

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a hint...

Maybe it's worth adding another approach, like you check the item(s) you want to drag, a bar appears at the top of the screen (like in file managers for copy, cut and paste), you click the button in that bar, then scroll to the group you want to paste (copy) into, click the group and that's it?

Comment: I already implemented copy paste option but now I need to implement in this way as well its my requirement